# androidx.navigation multiple destinations for menu item

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a single activity app using the androidx navigation library. For one of the menu destinations I effectively have a fragment as destination with no view whatsoever that depending on the state of the user provided configuration either redirects to the real destination that should be there or to one of currently two different views that tell the user that either he needs to setup a configuration first or that there currently is no active configuration (deleted?) and he needs to select one of the available configurations.

Now, functionally this approach works perfectly fine. However, since androidx navigation ties menu items to destinations by id the menu item that gets you to that view is **never** selected as it matches the fragment destination with no view in it.

I tried to add a `NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener` to my Activity and added it to the navController `navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(this)`. But it seems to get overwritten by the navigation afterwards.

```kotlin
override fun onDestinationChanged(controller: NavController, destination: NavDestination, arguments: Bundle?) {
    val destinations = listOf(R.id.destinationA, R.id.destinationB, R.id.destinationC)

    if(destinations.contains(destination.id)) {
        nav_view.menu.getItem(0).isChecked = true
    }
}
```

It is deffinitely the right menu item. As when I change `isChecked = true` to `isEnabled = false` I can no longer click on it.

Also when I do this odd hack it works

```kotlin
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    delay(1000)
    nav_view.menu.getItem(0).isChecked = true
}
```

Needless to say this is not a very good solution.

---

Anyone here knows how to overwride the default behaviour of androidx navigation in this regard?

I´ll come back to this later and report back if I find a proper solution to this.

Adding a listener to the drawer opening and setting the selected menu item then might be a good workaround for this if it is not possible to do currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `setupWithNavController()`,  as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer), setup it up yourself.

As mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#Tie-navdrawer), `onNavDestinationSelected()` helper method in `NavigationUI` is called when the menu item is clicked when you set it up using `setupWithNavController()`. So you could try something like this:

```kotlin
yourNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { item: MenuItem ->
    if(item.itemId == R.id.noViewFragmentId) {
        val isConfigurationProvided = ...
        if(!isConfigurationProvided) {
            //Perform your actions (navigate to either of the two alternate views)
            return@setNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
    }

    val success = NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)

    if(success) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        item.isChecked = true
    }
            
    success
}
```

Comment: This only works if you are navigating using the drawer though. And not if you are navigating by any other means. Looking at the code that´s actually inside setupWithNavController for the navView they also add a destination change listener to the navController and that´s where they actually set what menu item is selected. Upon finding that out I realized I can also put the listener I initially wrote in my question below the code that runs setupWithNavController for the navigation view and then it also works. I didn´t think that setupWithNavController is actually completely optional. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I´ll add this as a possible solution and stick with it for the time being. I still feel like there should be a better way to do this, so I will not accept it as an awnswer.

It´s essentially the idea I got at the end of writing the question

> Adding a listener to the drawer opening and setting the selected menu item then might be a good workaround for this if it is not possible to do currently.

```kotlin
class SetActiveMenuDrawerListener(
        private val navController: NavController,
        navigationView: NavigationView) : DrawerLayout.DrawerListener {

    private var checked = false
    private val destinations = listOf(R.id.destinationA, R.id.destinationB, R.id.destinationC)
    private val menu = navigationView.menu.getItem(0)

    init {
        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, _, _ -> checked = false }
    }

    override fun onDrawerSlide(drawerView: View, slideOffset: Float) {
    }

    override fun onDrawerOpened(drawerView: View) {
    }

    override fun onDrawerClosed(drawerView: View) {
    }

    override fun onDrawerStateChanged(newState: Int) {
        if(checked) return
        val currentDestination = navController.currentDestination ?: return

        if(destinations.contains(currentDestination.id)) {
            menu.isChecked = true
        }
        checked = true
    }
}
```

Then add this to the DrawerLayout

```kotlin
drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(SetActiveMenuDrawerListener(navController, nav_view))
```

I did add the code into the `onDrawerStateChanged` instead `onDrawerOpened`, because `onDrawerOpened` gets called a bit late if clicking the drawer and not at all while dragging it.

It´s not the pretties thing to look at, but it gets the job done.